# Azure Resource Group has no usage or billing

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I've got a trial Azure subscription running with a couple of cloud services projects, a VM, a web app etc all up and running for a couple of weeks now.

Usage is light but resources are being consumed. i.e. stuffs been done.

My problem is the breakdown of charges re: resource groups. Perhaps I misunderstand but I thought that since every resource is put in a group and only one group by default then whatever is billed for the period should essentially be the sum of the charges for each of the resource groups?

The docs say you can get a *consolidated view* of resource group costs like below:

[image]

But the reality is quite different. From this summary on the portal home screen:

[image]

I can drill in to find the $48.32 expenditure:

[image]

I can drill into that and get cost by resource:

[image]

But when I want to get the cost by resource groups the info is either missing or incomplete. For these resource groups:

[image]

only one, containing a VM, has any billing data but only for compute. No data charges or storage charges.

[image]

And all the rest just have no usage or billing.

[image]

So this is kinda useless to me since we still have to dig around to find out where the difference went.

The documentation and some of the build 2015 videos suggest you can get a comprehensive view of your costs by resource group.

- "how much is the marketing dept costing us"
- "You can clarify billing for your organization by viewing the rolled-up costs for the entire group."

But that doesn't seem to be the case at all. Out of $48.32 of expenditure (albeit comped) only $8.43 is accounted for in resource group costings.

So have I not set something up correctly or does the portal not in fact support this?

Can I get this info by cross referencing (costs by resource IDS) with (resource group member resources id) via Powershell?

How do i get the complete operating cost (compute, storage, data) for a given resource group?

Comment: Also curious about the answer to this. Do the [new Azure billing APIs](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-azure-billing-apis-available) need to be used to access more granular detail?